# get many to many with where clause in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I Have this 3 tables like below :

- Tools
- Parts
- Part_details

it is my the table structure :

```
Tool -> has many -> parts. part -> has many->part_details.

Tool : id*, name; Parts : id*, name, tool_id; part_details: id, part_id, total;
```

Question : 
Using `laravel` Model, how can I get Tool with One part that has **`biggest total on parts_details`** ??

Comment: What did you do? You can read the [Eloquent: Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) documentation if you are a newbie to this.

Comment: Should a single `PartDetail` have the `biggest total`? Or are you referring to the sum of `total` per `Part`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I expected PartDetail to return only one result with biggest total.

Answer (score 0):

// Tool Model

```
public function parts(){
   return $this->hasMany(Part::class);
}
```

// Part Model

```
public function part(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Tool::class);
}
public function part_details(){
  return $this->hasMany(PartDetail::class);
}
```

// PartDetail Model

```
public function part(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Part::class);
}
```

Now query the Tool model

```
$tools = Tool::with('parts')->withCount('parts.part_details')->get();
$toolWithMaxCount = $tools->filter(function($tool) use ($tools){
   return $tool->parts->max('par_details_count') === $tools->max('parts.part_details_count');
})->first();
```

You can improve this with adding some raw bindings to optimise it. I think you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use the the **hasManyThrough** Relationship to get the all part details related to tool and then you can check the one by one record and get the highest total of the tool part.

**// Tool Model**

```
public function partsdetails()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\PartDetail', 'App\Part','tool_id','part_id');
}
```

**In Your controller**

```
$data = Tool::all(); 
        $array = [];
        if(isset($data) && !empty($data)) {

            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
               $array[$value->id] = Tool::find($value->id)->partsdetails()->sum('total');
            }
        }

        if(is_array($array) && !empty($array)) {
            $maxs = array_keys($array, max($array));
            print_r($maxs);
        } 
        else{
         echo "No Data Available";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tool model

```
public function parts() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Part');
}
```

Part Model

```
public function details() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\PartDetail');
}

public function tool() {
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tool');
}
```

Detail Model

```
public function part() {
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Part');
}
```

Controller

```
$tools = Tool::with('parts', 'parts.details')
             ->find($id)
             ->max('parts.part_details');
```